# Configure nginx load balancer to better handle upstream 500 errors?

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have a cluster load balanced using nginx with 3 backend HTTP servers defined as the upstream servers. How can I configure nginx to failover to the next HTTP server in the cluster if one of the HTTP upstream servers throws an HTTP 500 error?

Answer (score 2):

Set [`proxy_next_upstream`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream) to include `http_500` as one of the values.